# Oracle DB: Why does rewriting this query a bit make it many times faster?

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database, sqlperformance

I had a query that was taking ~90 seconds to execute. After re-writing the query *slightly* differently, the query runs in 1.5 seconds. Can you explain why it's running faster?

## Context

I have a query which takes a list of records - joins those records to a list of assets, and joins those assets to a list of people, and joins those people to another list of people (their managers).

For the sake of illustration, lets say we're talking about a new list of sales leads, and we want to join those leads to the services we're selling, as well as the owners of those services, and their managers.

## Tables

There's 3 objects we're pulling from:

1) The 'sales_leads' table - a simple, local table of stuff with one index:

- It has foreign key 'asset_id', and 'is_live' and others.
- asset_id is indexed
- it has ~5k rows

2) the 'services' table - a simple, local table of other stuff:

- it has primary key 'asset_id' which is indexed (and a few other columns)
- it has columns like 'availability' and 'status'
- It has a value for 'asset_owner' - a foreign key to the
- This table has ~50,000 rows, most of which this query doesn't return

3) The 'vw_people_Data' view - a view wrapping A remote table:

- vw_people_Data is essentially just (create view vw_people_Data as select * from our_people_table@our_database_link)
- this table contains both owners and managers (and everyone else)
- This table has ~80,000 rows, most of which this query doesn't return

## The slow query

This query returns 557 rows in ~90 seconds:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM sales_leads leads
    LEFT OUTER JOIN services srvc ON (leads.asset_id = srvc.asset_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            c.emp_id,
            c.display_name,
            c.primary_email_address,
            c.functional_manager_emp_id,
        FROM vw_people_Data c
      )m1 ON (m1.emp_id = srvc.asset_owner)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT 
            c.emp_id, 
            c.primary_email_address 
        FROM vw_people_Data c
      )m2 ON m1.functional_manager_emp_id = m2.emp_id

    WHERE srvc.availability like 'A%'
    AND srvc.status = 'true'
    AND leads.is_live like 'Live'
    ;
```

## The 'fast' query:

This query returns 557 rows in 1.5 seconds:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM sales_leads leads
    LEFT OUTER JOIN services srvc ON (leads.asset_id = srvc.asset_id)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
          (
            SELECT 
              m1.emp_id m1_emp_id,
              m1.display_name m1_display_name,
              m1.primary_email_address m1_email,
              m2.emp_id m2_emp_id,
              m2.primary_email_address m2_email
            FROM vw_people_Data m1
            LEFT OUTER JOIN 
              (
                    SELECT 
                      c.emp_id,
                      c.primary_email_address
                    FROM vw_people_Data c
              ) m2 ON (m1.functional_manager_emp_id = m2.emp_id)
          ) m1_m2 ON (srvc.asset_owner = m1_m2.m1_emp_id)

    WHERE srvc.availability like 'A%'
    AND srvc.status = 'true'
    AND leads.is_live like 'Live'
    ;
```

## The question:

Why? Why the big improvement in query time from such a minor re-writing of the query? What is the optimizer doing that's so different?

I've looked at the execution plans and they look identical.

Comment: You need to look at the execution plans to answer this question.  All bets on optimization options are off when you are using views with no definitions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the only view is the vw_people_Data which is defined as select * from tbl@our_db_link as described above

Comment: you could create a plan with rowsource statistics using the Hint /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ for example to get a plan with actual execution timing. This should at least show where the time is spend.

Comment: Are those timings repeatable - or is the second, fast, query just benefiting from data that was cached during execution of the first, slow, query?

Comment: by the way: sometime even the same execution plan may result in different performance because of the decisions of the runtime engine. For example a `serial direct path access` for a full table scan would not be visible in the plan but could result in a faster or slower execution (though the question does not indicate that this kind of difference could explain something in the given case)

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes they're repeatable. Even if I add change comments or aliases (which I understand causes cached results to not be used) the results are still the same.

Answer (score 2):

Tuning advice without seeing the Explain Plans for the two queries is a mug's game. But let's have a guess.

It seems the key point is this:

> the only view is the vw_people_Data which is defined as
>   `select *from tbl@our_db_link`
>   `................^`

The *"minor"* change to the query is a re-write of the access path to this view which queries a table on a remote database. Performance tuning joins across database links is tricky. Basically the remote database sends all its candidate data to the local database where the joins are evaluated and the non-matches discarded.

In your first query you have two subqueries on the remote view so you get remote two results delivered to the local database. In your second version you have one subquery which applies joins in the remote database. Consequently the result set sent to the local database is much smaller, because all the non-matching `vw_people` records have been discarded.